# How to remove pixels from a HTML 5 video?

Tags: html, canvas

What I have so far: http://sem.serialshop.nl/video/

My goal is to manipulate the video pixels to show corresponding information inside the pupil when hovering one of the buttons. Can I delete the pixels inside the pupil, and replace it with an image?

Comment: Please make sure you post your code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: If you want to "replace" part of the video with an image, can't you just show the image above the video? (e.g. in absolute position).

Answer (score 0):

**Removing pixels from an mp4 video—removing pixels of an eye pupil**

As darma says, you can probably finish your project by just using context.drawImage() to superimpose your image over the pupil.  Here's how you do that.

Also, here's how you would remove the pixels of the pupil (as you asked).

**Background**

You can take an mp4 video and draw it frame-by-frame into a canvas.

The canvas drawing rate is quick enough that the results look as good as  the video they were taken from.

More interestingly, you can manipulate each frame as it’s drawn into the canvas.  This allows you to take the pixels of the pupil and replace them.

Manipulating pixels:

- You manipulate the canvas frame by using context.getImageData() to grab the pixels into a data array.
- Then you manipulate the data array in whatever way you wish.
- Finally, you put the modified data array back into the canvas using context.putImageData().
- The canvas then shows the modified pixels!

**Your Solution**

To solve your problem, we get the bounding-box containing the pupil.  Every time we see a nearly-black pixel in that bounding box, we know it’s the pupil and we can modify that nearly-black pixel.  In the following working code, we just change the pixel from nearly-black to pure red. However, you can do whatever you desire to the pupil pixels.

Here is code to draw the video with the pupil pixels colored red:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var centerX=315;
    var centerY=150;
    var radius=10;
    var rx=267;
    var ry=98;
    var rwidth=101;
    var rheight=95;

    var video = document.getElementById('vid');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var cw = 638;
    var ch = 358;
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;

    video.addEventListener('play', function(){
        draw(this,ctx,cw,ch);
    },false);

    function draw(video,context,w,h) {
        if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
        context.drawImage(video,0,0,w,h);

        // at this point you could also draw a second image
        // into the pupil of the eye like this
        // context.drawImage(myImage,rx,ry,rwidth,rheight);

        // but what we do here is just put a red bounding box
        // around the pupil so that we can see we are 
        // properly focusing on the pupil area

        context.fillStyle="blue";
        context.strokeStyle="red";
        context.lineWidth=2;
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(rx,ry,rwidth,rheight);
        context.stroke();
        extractPupil(context);
        setTimeout(draw,150,video,context,w,h);
    }

    function extractPupil(context){
        // get just the bounding rectangle of the pupil
        // NOT the whole canvas.
        var imgData=context.getImageData(rx,ry,rwidth,rheight);
        var data=imgData.data;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){

            // if the pixel color is nearly black--change it to red
            if(data[i]<20 && data[i+1]<20 && data[i+2]<20){
                data[i]=255;
                data[i+1]=0;
                data[i+2]=0;
            }

        }
        // put the modified pixels back into the canvas
        // Now the pupil is colored pure red!
        context.putImageData(imgData,rx,ry);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <video id="vid" controls loop>
        <source src="eye.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```